# Exclude Permissions from an Admin AWS Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I want to create a user who has `AdministratorAccess` and manage everything except for example deny Delete and Update actions in IAM

I tried to do this

- Create Admin User
- Create a policy that denies Delete and Update Operations in IAM
- Attach that policy to the user
- User has now (AdministratorAccess + MyPolicy)

But

- User is still able to delete and update users in IAM
- I think this is because `AdministratorAccess`

Is there a way to do this, without trying to create a complicated multiple Policies ?

## Update

Here is the policy I created

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StmtXXXX",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:DeleteAccountAlias",
                "iam:DeleteAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteGroup",
                "iam:DeleteGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteSAMLProvider",
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:DeleteServerCertificate",
                "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
                "iam:DeleteUser",
                "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:RemoveClientIDFromOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile",
                "iam:RemoveUserFromGroup",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::1234:user/dummyadmin"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

## Update 2

After setting resource to `arn:aws:iam::1234`, it worked!

Comment: `Deny` in an IAM policy *always* overrides `Allow`, if both rules apply to a user... AdministratorAccess should not be exempt from this, so so the most likely explanation is that your deny policy doesn't correctly identity the actions and resources to which you want to deny access.  Show the deny policy?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I attached the policy I created, could it be because of ARN ?

Comment: The `Effect` of a policy statement applies when a `Principal` tries to perform an `Action` **against** a *target* `Resource`.  The `Principal` is not declared in a user policy, because the `Principal` is any user against whom the policy is applied... so by confusing `Resource` and `Principal`, this was only denying user/dummyadmin from performing actions against itself.

Answer (score 3):

A potentially easier option is to assign permissions for **everything except IAM**. This can accomplished with this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": "iam:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the use of `NotAction` to exclude IAM.

It's not quite the same as your policy (which can use `CreateUser`), but is a very efficient way to give somebody **Power User** permissions, without the ability to use IAM.

Answer (score 1):

Chance resource to

```
arn:aws:iam::1234
```